# Using stored procedure (dynamic tsql) in entity framework 6 MVC 5

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure as:

```
Create PROCEDURE DynamicReportQuery
( @startDateInput datetime = NULL, @endDateInput datetime = NULL) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
BEGIN
DECLARE 
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@selcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime,
@paramdef nvarchar(max)

SET @startdate = @startDateInput
SET @enddate = @endDateInput
SET @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';


SELECT 
@selcols = STUFF((SELECT ','+'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) + ', 0) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SELECT 
@cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120)) 
               FROM AdeccoView
               --where datein > @startdate
               --    and datein <= @enddate
               GROUP BY [Date]
               ORDER BY [Date]
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT CreatedBy,Name, Surname,EventTypeID,Event, '+ @selcols + ',Total
    from 
    (
        select av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy,emp.Name,emp.Surname,Event,
            convert(varchar(10), [Date], 120) [Date],
            row_number() over(PARTITION BY [date],av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy  order BY av.EventTypeID,av.CreatedBy ) m,
            count(*) over(partition by av.CreatedBy,av.EventTypeId) Total
        from AdeccoView av
        left join EventType et on et.EventTypeID = av.EventTypeID
        left join Employee emp on av.CreatedBy = emp.EmployeeD

    ) x
    pivot 
    (
        max(m)
        for [Date] in ('+@cols+')
    ) p '
END

exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startDateInput, @enddate =@EndDateInput;
```

From some reason when I go on update Entity in vs2013, it won't update that procedure. I've read somewhere that is the problem with dynamic reports and EF 6 in mvc 5?
Shall I move SQL query and adopt it in order to create View?

Answer (score 0):

you can create Complex type in the entity Model first and then map the output of Store procedure to the complex type created.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have some links or something how I can be able to see further steps in details? Thanks